# Why the shell script gives me a too many argument error?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ !\(-f new.bash -o -d new.bash\) ]
then
    echo "Neither"
else
    echo "yes"
fi
```

it works but leaves an error:

```
/file_exist_or_not.bash      
./file_exist_or_not.bash: line 3: [: too many arguments
yes
```

BTW, Why the inner parenthesises needs to be escaped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash uses spaces to separate tokens, which are then passed as arguments to the commands (in this case the command is `test`). See the man page for `test` for more details.

To solve, you need to add spaces between the operands.

```
if [ ! \( -f new.bash -o -d new.bash \) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, It makes sense to me, could you tell me Why the inner parenthesises needs to be escaped?

Comment: Otherwise bash will see the inner parentheses first and try to interpret them itself instead of passing them to `test`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `bash` and don't mind giving up POSIX compatibility, the following is a little simpler:

```
if [[ ! ( -f new.bash || -d new.bash ) ]]; then
```

You can use `||` instead of `-o`, and the parentheses don't need to be escaped.

Comment: +1 for the elegant style, what kind of shell could cause problem for this syntax